# Jquery if field is empty, on click of button disable it

Tags: jquery, input

I have a input field with class "kind" and link/button with class "submit".

Now I wanna disable this "kind" input on click of button "submit" if there is no value in input, or if you wanna say, if input is empty...

I tried like this:

html:

```
<input class="kind" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Kind">

    <a href="#" class="submit" >Submit</a>
```

script:

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
    if ($('.kind').val().length != 0) {
        $('.kind').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

but it does not work, and I don't know why, you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/UBy4x/

am I missing something? or should I define value check differently..

Comment: $('.kind').val().length == 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you meant to use `==` instead of `!=` in your conditional statement, if you wanted it to match an empty case.

Also, you should use [**`$.trim`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove any whitespace, otherwise an empty input with spaces won't trigger match the conditional statement.

```
if ($.trim($('.kind').val()).length === 0){
  $('.kind').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UBy4x/6/)

Comment: I think that this will fit my needs

Comment: @dzordz No worries, remember to use $.trim like I mentioned, or an empty input with spaces will not disable the button :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `.val()`

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
    if (!$('.kind').val()) {
        $('.kind').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/atif089/UBy4x/7/

Comment: It is not working. Try to enter some value in textbox then it is show as disable.

Comment: @Amit, you are right, I think I used a wrong method here. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is inverse of what you want from it. You simply have to update your condition. It should be if that value `==0`

```
$('.submit').click( function() {
    if ($('.kind').val().length == 0){
          $('.kind').prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('.submit').click( function() {
    if ($('.kind').val().length < 1){
          $('.kind').prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('.kind').attr('disabled', true);
```